# polite tag in questions : for me?

Tags: questions, politeness, prepositional-phrases, pragmatics

in the question "What's your last name for me?" asked by a clerk for a registration, does the prepositional **for me** soften it?

00:12 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFjrerZ-EWo

Answer (score 2):

It's ungrammatical and doesn't really make sense.  "for me" would normally follow you asking someone to **do something**, like *"Can you spell your last name for me?".*

If you want to "soften" (which which I take it you mean 'make more friendly or welcoming')  "What's your last name?" then you can say ***"What's your last name, please?"*** or ***"Please can you tell me your last name?"***

PS that video is creepy.

Comment: +1 It's a new trend "ASMR". You will find the weirdest of these having millions of subscribers. I did find a few to be actually interesting.

Comment: @NVZ well that's my "weird new internet thing of the day" box ticked, cheers.

Comment: Then how can we explain it, her being a native speaker?

Comment: Native speakers make language errors all the time.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I do not think this is a linguistic error at all.

Comment: @GJC "What is your last name for me?" is a terrible sentence.  It doesn't make sense.  Do you have a last name for me and a different last name for someone else?  I just have one last name, and it's that same last name for everyone.